# iterate over two lists using a while loop instead of a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
colours = ["red", "green", "blue"]
clothes = ["shirt", "dress", "pants", "jacket", "hat"]


for colour_item in colours:
    for clothes_item in clothes:
        print("I am wearing a ",colour_item," ",clothes_item)
```

This is the code i am trying to change into while loops to produce all outcomes, ie 15 outcomes, the best i can get with while loops is 3.

Comment: Why would you want to use a while loop for this?

Comment: Include your while loop code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a while loop while also keeping an index counter variable for each list, though it is essentially just a for loop:

```
colours = ["red", "green", "blue"]
clothes = ["shirt", "dress", "pants", "jacket", "hat"]

colorIndex = 0
while(colorIndex < len(colours)):
  clothesIndex = 0
  while(clothesIndex < len(clothes)):
    print("I am wearing a",colours[colorIndex],clothes[clothesIndex])
    clothesIndex += 1
  colorIndex += 1
```

Output:

```
I am wearing a red shirt
I am wearing a red dress
I am wearing a red pants
I am wearing a red jacket
I am wearing a red hat
I am wearing a green shirt
I am wearing a green dress
I am wearing a green pants
I am wearing a green jacket
I am wearing a green hat
I am wearing a blue shirt
I am wearing a blue dress
I am wearing a blue pants
I am wearing a blue jacket
I am wearing a blue hat
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to do a little math, you can do this in a single `while` loop.

```
colours = ["red", "green", "blue"]
clothes = ["shirt", "dress", "pants", "jacket", "hat"]

n = 0
l = len(clothes)

while n < len(colours) * len(clothes):
    print(f"I am wearing a {colours[n // l]}  {clothes[n % l]}")
    n += 1
```

Which prints the expected:

```
I am wearing a red  shirt
I am wearing a red  dress
I am wearing a red  pants
I am wearing a red  jacket
I am wearing a red  hat
I am wearing a green  shirt
I am wearing a green  dress
I am wearing a green  pants
I am wearing a green  jacket
I am wearing a green  hat
I am wearing a blue  shirt
I am wearing a blue  dress
I am wearing a blue  pants
I am wearing a blue  jacket
I am wearing a blue  hat
```

Comment: I don't think this is more efficient though, it's still O(n^2)

Comment: @AnikethMalyala considering the OP wants to print `m * n` items `O(n * m)` seems impossible to beat. This is expressed pretty clearly in the loop `len(colours) * len(clothes)`

Comment: O(m*n), my bad. I thought you were implying that your singular while loop was more efficient than nested ones, my bad!

Comment: @AnikethMalyala I can see how it seemed that way. But no, just making the code shorter (but maybe not more clear).  Personally, I think `for` loops or `itertools.product` are the correct way to do this.

Comment: Fr, using a for each loop seams much better in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
colours = ["red", "green", "blue"]
clothes = ["shirt", "dress", "pants", "jacket", "hat"]

i=0
while i<len(colours):
    j=0
    colour_item = colours[i]
    while j<len(clothes):
        clothes_item = clothes[j]
        print("I am wearing a ",colour_item," ",clothes_item)
        j+=1
    i+=1
```